# Insert picture in Excel from file in vba

Tags: vba, image, excel

I would like to insert a picture in Excel from a file depending on a cell value.
I have a set of pictures in a file, each with a different name.

In Excel, I have a table that is populated with a list of names, depending on certain criteria. The list is a group of words that are the same as the picture's names.

Is there a way through which I can upload the pictures to Excel, when the picture name appears in the list?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you show an example of the table?

Comment: So I have a table with a list of animals:

Dog, Cat, Snake, Iguana.
I have the images with the same names on a folder. However, I would only want the images to appear if the animal's name is on the table. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Consider this methodology.

```
Sub InsertPics()
Dim fPath As String, fName As String
Dim r As Range, rng As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
fPath = "C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\"
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
i = 1

For Each r In rng
    fName = Dir(fPath)
    Do While fName <> ""
        If fName = r.Value Then
            With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(fPath & fName)
                .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
                Set px = .ShapeRange
                If .ShapeRange.Width > Rows(i).Columns(2).Width Then .ShapeRange.Width = Columns(2).Width
                    With Cells(i, 2)
                        px.Top = .Top
                        px.Left = .Left
                        .RowHeight = px.Height
                    End With
            End With
        End If
        fName = Dir
    Loop
    i = i + 1
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

' Note: you need the file extension, such as ',jpg', or whatever you are using, so you can match on that.
```